# Firestore Object in Object in Array Access React Native

Tags: arrays, react-native, object, google-cloud-firestore

How can I access a deeply nested value? I use Firestore and I'm mapping the doc data to a state. This state is an Array containing multiple objects, each with another Object called "data". How can I access values of that second object?

Console logging the state:

```
Array [
   Object {
      "data": Object {
         "value a": "...",
         "value b": "...",
         "value c": "...",
      },
      "id": "...",
   },
   Object {
      "data": Object {
         "value a": "...",
         "value b": "...",
         "value c": "...",
      },
      "id": "...",
   },
  .....
]
```

How do I access for example all value a's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking to have, for example, an array of just the values at "value a", you can use the [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) array method. Here's how I would do it:

```
const stateData = [
   {
      "data": Object {
         "value a": "...",
         "value b": "...",
         "value c": "...",
      },
      "id": "...",
   },
   {
      "data": Object {
         "value a": "...",
         "value b": "...",
         "value c": "...",
      },
      "id": "...",
   },
  .....
]

const arrayOfValueAs = stateData.map((stateObj) => stateObj.data["value a"]);
```

Your resulting array will have only the "value a" values in it.